# Is there a way to create a semi-transparent window with Allegro?

Tags: transparency, alpha-transparency, allegro

Is there a way to create a display (a window) using allegro, in such way that the background of the window would be translucent.
In SDL2 we can achieve that result using this little bit of code:

SDL_SetWindowOpacity(window, 0.5);